# Sql Server - Force server to use specific plan

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

I have two databases with the same schema. One for production another for a test environment. When I run a query on each of them I return different execution plans (what makes sense). How can I force the SQL Server to choose a specific plan?

Comment: [How to Use the USE PLAN Hint](https://forrestmcdaniel.com/2018/07/19/how-to-use-the-use-plan-hint/)

Comment: Yes we can enforce a execution plan, please read ,https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/the-sql-server-2016-query-store-forcing-execution-plans-using-the-query-store/

Comment: @DenisRubashkin Ajeet Verma thank you for giving  two different ways it would be good to put it in the form of an answer

Comment: You can also use the Query Store GUI built into SSMS which will allow you to Force a plan and give you some actually vastly improved visual graphs and data for comparing execution times and resource consumption.

Comment: Lets not forget about our friend the PLAN GUIDE: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/create-a-plan-guide-for-parameterized-queries?view=sql-server-ver15